# Filtrar números ainda não cadastradas via SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tentando encontrar os números que ainda não foram cadastrados no banco.

Eu tenho uma tabela de cliente, nela eu tenho os campos `codigo` e `nome`.

Quando o usuário cadastra o cliente, ele coloca o código manualmente, portanto corre o risco de ele pular alguns números.

Existe alguma maneira via `SQL` para eu tentar selecionar esses números que ainda não foram cadastradas?

Comment: Algum motivo para não usar uma chave primaria incremental como código ?

Comment: A coluna "codigo" é do tipo inteiro?

Comment: É do tipo inteiro sim e chave primaria. É que na verdade o usuário determina o numero para cadastrar

Comment: @Emerson ai que mora o perigo. Ele realmente precisa determinar o número? Por que ? Não vejo um bom motivo para permitir isso.

Comment: Então @gmsantos, eu achei uma maneira diferente, um sistema que chama mais a atenção. Porque quero colocar do lado o numero que ainda não foi cadastrado!

Comment: Isso que você quer é possível com `SEQUENCE`. Você consegue prever qual será o proximo codigo =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emerson,

Para verificar quais codigos não foram cadastrados no intervalo, pode executar a query abaixo, alterando o nome da tabela.

```
DECLARE @CONTADOR INTEGER
DECLARE @TT INTEGER

CREATE TABLE #CODIGO (
CODIGO INTEGER )

SET @CONTADOR = 1


WHILE ((SELECT MAX(CODIGO) FROM TABELA) >= @CONTADOR)
BEGIN
    SET @TT = (SELECT COUNT(CODIGO) FROM TABELA WHERE CODIGO = @CONTADOR)

IF @TT = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #CODIGO VALUES (@CONTADOR)
END

SET @CONTADOR = @CONTADOR + 1

END

SELECT * FROM #CODIGO
DROP TABLE #CODIGO
```

Comment: Estamos falando de usuários. E se algum usuário definir o valor máximo do integer como código?

Comment: Jean, na verdade eu não preciso pegar sempre o último numero e adicionar mais 1. Preciso verificar se existe algum numero que foi pulado na hora de cadastrar!

Comment: Ah sim, vou preparar a query para você! Já edito.

Comment: Emerson, editei.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates, esta dando nessa query. Não manjo muito em bd... Estou utilizando Postgresql e parece que a sintaxe muda muito neh?

Answer (score 1):

Seria até simples de fazer isso:

Faça uma pesquisa na mesma tabela antes de adicionar um novo registro e pegue o retorno e adicione o código em um array e depois na hora de adicionar compare se o código digitado pelo usuário esta dentro deste array.

É uma forma bem simples de fazer.

Comment: Obrigado Maicon. Mas vc tem um exemplo de como seria esse array?

Comment: Depende da linguagem de programação que você usa, tem várias maneiras de se fazer isso mas considere realmente usar um campo incremental para sua segurança e de seu cliente.

Comment: Ok Maicon, vou tentar aqui. Mas foi como falei, gostaria de que esse sistema fique um pouco diferente, sair do padrão...

Comment: Mas vai por mim cara, esse padrão vai acabar dando dor de cabeça pra você e seu cliente com esse método é muito mais fácil dar problema de índice mais tarde e se perder quando usar uma FK por exemplo, é um controle desnecessário você ter que fazer, deixe tudo com o banco por que ele foi feito pra isso mas se quiser fazer como esta fazendo continue tranquilamente mas cuidando muito de como vai implementar.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica Maicon, mas vou tentar fazer sim.. Vou tomar o máximo de cuidado =)

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja usando um [`SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html) é possível prever qual será o próximo `codigo` a ser inserido.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE codigoUsuario;
```

Para selecionar o código:

```
SELECT nextval('codigoUsuario');
```

Ao criar a sua tabela você pode definir a `SEQUENCE` diretamente no campo:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela ( codigo INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('codigoUsuario') );
```

Não acho uma boa ideia deixar o controle de códigos na mão do usuário.

Precisar verificar se já existe um determinado novo código na hora da criação só vai criar mais complexidade na aplicação, o que sem um caso de uso realmente factível é simplesmente desnecessário.

Comment: Então cara, não entendi muito. Esse nextval para que serve?

Comment: Ele verifica qual será o próximo número a ser inserido. Exemplo: Você faz um  `SELECT nextval('codigoUsuario');` e retorna 5. Em seguida vc faz um insert que envolve essa sequence. Na proxima vez que vc fizer um `SELECT nextval('codigoUsuario')` irá retornar 6.

Comment: Ele da esse erro: relação "per_codigo" não existe. Tem ave com a sequencia ne?

Comment: Sim, você precisa criar a `SEQUENCE` no banco antes. Leia a documentação no link. Ele é como uma chave incremental fora da tabela.

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum link. E sobre a sequencia, eu criei o código como uma chave primaria so que sem sequencia e nem auto increment.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: gmsantos, o problema dele é descobrir quais números não foram cadastrados entre os períodos de códigos já cadastrados.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates no fundo ele não tem esse problema, como notei nos comentários ele quer "um sistema diferente que chama mais a atenção" e não vejo como uma boa prática permitir que o usuário controle as chaves primarias.

Comment: Eu ate entendo @gmsantos, mas preciso muito do sistema dessa maneira. Estou recebendo ordens aqui...

Comment: Emerson, o SEQUENCE vai de encontro com parte do que você disse. Mas cabe a vc também apontar para o seu chefe ou arquiteto responsável que isso é uma má pratica e provavelmente irá causar problemas futuros. Pense, se isso fosse uma boa ideia outros programadores fariam dessa forma, certo?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT linha
  FROM (SELECT DECODE(codigo,linha,'N','S') AS  proximo
              ,linha
                 FROM (SELECT codigo
                             ,ROWNUM linha
                             ,nome 
                         FROM cliente
                        ORDER BY codigo))                          
 WHERE proximo = 'S'
   AND ROWNUM = 1
```

O exemplo acima eu fiz com oracle, ele torna o próximo número válido. Se ajudou marque como certo, valeu.

Comment: Kelvin, necessito dessa maneira para ser um sistema diferente mesmo, onde o cliente pode colocar o numero que desejar...
Nesse seu exemplo não da certo amigo! =/

Comment: Deixa eu entender, eu sou o cliente e quero fazer um cadastro, porém nesta tabela existem dois registro, código 1 e código 3. Caso o usuário queira cadastrar com o código 7 por exemplo, o que deveria acontecer?

Comment: Ele deixaria passar normalmente, Dai nesse exemplo o próximo código livre na base de dados seria o código 2. Gostaria de mostrar na tela isso!

Comment: Editei com a resposta correta.

Comment: Se não me engano teria que trocar os ROWNUM por row_number() para postgre,

Comment: Consegue me explicar ao que esse sql faz? Acredito que não faz sentido para o que eu precise

Comment: Por exemplo em uma tabela com os códigos 1, 2, 5, 7 , 10 a query irá retorna qual será o próximo código disponível, que para o exemplo seria 3.

Comment: Funcionou para você?

Comment: Estou utilizado postgreSQL, e apesar de não muito conhecimento em sql, vou tentar ainda ok? Estou saindo agora mas amanha ja coloco em prática

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, não consegui passar isso não cara. Codigo e linha? Desculpa pela minha ignorância mas não entendi nada ainda =/